# Difference between send() and triggerAction()

Tags: ember.js

I'm sending an event from a view to its parent view. Now I have two solutions that work:

```
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
  somethingHappened: function() {
    this.get('parentView').send('anAction');
  })
});
```

or

```
App.View = Ember.View.extend(Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport, {
  somethingHappened: function() {
    this.triggerAction({
      action: 'anAction',
      target: this.get('parentView')
    });    
  })
});
```

What is the difference in the two methods? I can't figure out from the API in what cases I should use `triggerAction` from the `ViewTargetActionSupport` mixin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [source for triggerAction](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/target_action_support.js#L124) you will see that it uses `send()` internally. In my opinion it seems that `triggerAction` is mostly a nice wrapper around `send`, though I haven't used it before and just relied on `send`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, when I look at the source I can see that `triggerAction` doesn't do that much more except for setting the action target.

Answer (score 1):

`triggerAction` bubbles an event. `send` and `sendAction` require an action coming up from the component itself.

`triggerAction` in the component's controller will work with only `{{component-name}}` in the template.

Where as, `send` requires something like `{{component-name onConfirm=(action='doItNow')}}`